One software (mdadm) RAID array from 2 separate controllers?
I have a motherboard with two sets of four(4) SATA ports. One set of four(4) is part of the Intel Z270 Chipset. The other set is on an ASMedia chip.
I need a RAID5 array with at least five(5) HDD's out of the eight(8) SATA ports.
Is it possible as a software RAID using mdadm to combine the two(2) different controllers into one RAID5 array, possibly using all eight(8) drives?
In case you need the information:
Motherboard: ASUS ROG Maximus IX Extreme
Processor: Core i7-6700K

